# Unpack 8 byte integer

Tags: php

I am trying to upack one 8 byte integer, the same way the following 4 byte is unpacked:

```
print_r(unpack("N", "ACD0"));//just as expected, I get 1094927408
```

8 Bytes:

```
$value = "ACD0DSAS";//I expect this to be unpacked in one 8 byte number
$higher = unpack("N", substr($value, 0, 4));
$lower = unpack("N", substr($value, 4, 4));
echo //the number
```

Is there a way to do this in PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$value = "ACD0DSAS"; //I expect this to be unpacked in one 8 byte number
$higher = unpack("N", substr($value, 0, 4));
$lower = unpack("N", substr($value, 4, 4));

echo ($higher[1] << 32) + $lower[1]; // 4702677410000355667
```

Using bcmath

```
echo bcadd(bcmul($higher[1], bcpow(2, 32)), $lower[1]); // 4702677410000355667
```

Without unpack:

```
echo hexdec(bin2hex($value)); // 4702677410000355667
// echo bindec($value); // does not work, i do not know why.
```

But result would be converted to float on 32 systems. Float could store maximum 9,007,199,254,740,992 value without loss.

Comment: @Luka, are you sure that your code is running under 64 system?

Comment: Thanks a lot it works! Is the accuracy of the number warranted?

Comment: @Luka Yes, bcmath is Arbitrary Precision Mathematics lib. Also first variant could return wrong value on 64 systems because N is unsigned and php integer always signed.